# Dynamically Initiate a class in another's constructor in Laravel (or php)

Tags: php, laravel, class, object, oop

To make it simple i have two classes:

```php
class AddressController extends ApiController
{
    private AddressRepository $addressRepository;

    public function __construct(AddressRepository $addressRepository)
    {
        $this->addressRepository = $addressRepository;
    }
//........
```

```php
class CountyController extends ApiController
{
    private CountyRepository $countyRepository;

    public function __construct(CountyRepository $countyRepository)
    {
        $this->countyRepository = $countyRepository;
    }
//........
```

As you can see I'm extending the `ApiController` class and use dependency injection for both (county/address) repository. 
My question is how to refactor it in a away everytime i extend from the ApiController, it create the repository property with the proper namespace.

Comment: I'm not really sure what exactly you are asking here. Is the answer provided by below about stubs the thing you want? Or are you asking how to inject the repository according to its given class, let's say `CountyController` will inject the `CountyRepository` by default and the same for every other class extending from `ApiController`?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I suggest to do some tweaks on your Laravel Stub, which can fulfill your requirement.
On publishing Laravel Controller from command, you can customize your namespace and the stuffs you require in controller.
You can publish your current stub file using artisan command

```
php artisan stub:publish
```

for more https://laravel-news.com/customizing-stubs-in-laravel